# Is there a way to reverse proxy a ReportViewer of SQL Server Report Service 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The problem is that I have to port a SSRS 2008 report viewer in a JSP. I've tried many ways, but all failed. I also figured out that it is almost impossible to tackle the UpdatePanel in the report viewer.

Can someone provide a proper solution for me?

Note: The SSRS 2008 requires Windows authentication, which must be properly handled as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit https://github.com/bytzdev/ssrsproxy

It need you configure the `web.xml` of tomcat to add `.aspx/.asd/.ReportServer` to `url-pattern` of servlet.

You could have a look at the `help.jsp` page for helping.